# Pareto Frontier generation for multi-objective prob. using openMDAO 1.x?

Tags: openmdao

I am new to the OpenMDAO framework and currently using the 1.5.0 version. I'm interested in generating a Pareto front for Zitzler–Deb–Thiele's functions using the same.

I found a solution for the legacy version [here](http://openmdao.org/forum/questions/794/how-do-you-model-multi-objective-problem-for-generating-a-pareto-frontier) which uses 'pareto_filter' but was unable to locate the same in the new version.
So, how do I set up a multi-objective problem to generate pareto front in 1.x version?

Thanks to all.

Comment: The solution depends on exactly what you're trying to do. Are you trying to set up some kind of adaptive sampling method like Efficient Global Optimization? Or do you simply want to use a multi-objective optimizer?

I need a bit more clarification before I can give you a better answer.

Comment: Just want to use a multi-objective optimizer. I'll mostly be using NSGA2 from pyopt for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to us NSGA2 from pyopt-sparse directly in OpenMDAO. You just install the [pyopt-sparse](https://bitbucket.org/mdolab/pyoptsparse) package and OpenMDAO has a [driver](http://openmdao.readthedocs.org/en/1.5.0/srcdocs/packages/drivers/pyoptsparse_driver.html) already built in that will let you use it. Then you pick NSGA2 as your optimizer.

The only issue is that, if you look at the [source](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/master/openmdao/drivers/pyoptsparse_driver.py#L83), that driver is currently labeled as single-objective. So you should change that line to True, so that you can specify multiple objectives.

We haven't tested NSGA2 via the pyopt-sparse. So it might take a little bit of hacking around to get it to work. If you'd prefer to us the regular [pyopt](http://www.pyopt.org/) package, you should be able to start with our current pyopt-sparse wrapper and make some small changes to get it to work.

Comment: I successfully ran NSGA2 for single-objective optimization using pyopt-sparse. I did change the multi-objective option to True. But, on adding the second objective function, it's giving the following error - http://pastebin.com/UpdqsuYi.
Any ideas?

Comment: can you post your actual model? There appears to be a bug in pyopt-sparse itself causing this. But it will be much easier to debug if you give code. It would probably be best to ask about this new bug in a new question

Comment: Okay, I've posted the model and the error [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148660/typeerror-while-using-nsga2-to-solve-multi-objective-prob-from-pyopt-sparse-i) as a separate question. Hope the bug is fixed soon.
Thanks.